How is the psychology behind TV rating system by age?
I am a 16 years old teenager. And recently I have watched a 18+ TV, and I feel kind of unconfortable, but it made me wondering why the Age system is supposed to be set this way, out of curiosity. Out of common sense, a kid can't be watching sex at an early age, but Why? Out of common reasoning, a kid can't be watching violence at an early age, because that would affect his/her behavior. But is there a deeper psychologically-theoretic level of explaining the phenomenon of the appearance of TV age rating? I am especially curious in the difference between "adult" and "teenager" in terms of the reason why they segregated these two terms while making the rating system.

It's set by politicians, the scientific backing for it may well have been a post-hoc thing. I'm merely stating this so you don't set your expectations too high for a definitive answer. There's a phenomenon known as the Overton window which may point you to the social-context of such decisions.

I agree with @JiminyCricket - this question is more likely to have a political answer than a psychological one. The concepts of teenager vs adult already existed for voting, drinking, driving, consent, etc, so were likely easier to piggie-back onto than inventing something new.
